# New column with row difference based on condition

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column difference in a data.frame according to condition, for example I have this data.frame :

```
    structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), Condition = c("a", "b", "a", 
"b"), Value = c(20, 30, 50, 45)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

  ID Condition Value
1  1         a    20
2  1         b    30
3  2         a    50
4  2         b    45
```

Then for each ID, I would like to obtain a new column with Value when Condition = a and Value difference b-a when Condition = b. On other words, I would like to obtain this but I'm struggling :

```
  ID Condition Value Diff
1  1         a    20   20
2  1         b    30   10
3  2         a    50   50
4  2         b    45   -5
```

How would you proceed to do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(ID, Condition) %>% 
   mutate(Diff = case_when(Condition == 'a' ~ Value, 
                            TRUE ~ Value - lag(Value)))

   ID Condition Value Diff
1  1         a    20   20
2  1         b    30   10
3  2         a    50   50
4  2         b    45   -5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Diff = replace(Value, Condition == 'b', Value[Condition == 'b'] - Value[Condition == 'a'])) %>%
  #Can also use ifelse if it is easier to understand
  #mutate(Diff = ifelse(Condition == 'b', Value[Condition == 'b'] - Value[Condition == 'a'], Value)) %>%
  ungroup

#     ID Condition Value  Diff
#  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 a            20    20
#2     1 b            30    10
#3     2 a            50    50
#4     2 b            45    -5
```

---

If in your real data you have only two conditions and want to subtract 2nd value with the 1st value this can also be reduced to -

```
df %>%
  arrange(ID, Condition) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Diff = replace(Value, n(), diff(Value)))
```